# sparse matrix multiplication only calculate upper triangle

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, scikit-learn

I am doing something about dedup strings.
My main working flow is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(some_path)
vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)
tfidf = vect.fit_transform(df.title.astype(unicode))

sml_matrix = (tfidf * tfidf.T)
sml_matrix = sml_matrix> similar_ratio
```

the sml_matrix would be like:

```
       │CHEESE CHORES GEESE  GLOVES
───────┼───────────────────────────
CHEESE │    1   0.222  0.177  0.444     
CHORES │0.222       1  0.422  0.333
GEESE  │0.177   0.422      1  0.300
GLOVES │0.444   0.333  0.300      1
```

Obviously, calculate sml_matrix's upper triangle is enough.

But I have no idea how to only calculate upper triangle with scipy.sparse matrix.(only forloop I can imagine ,but seems not so efficient)

**for loop example(just pseudo-code):**

```
A = tfidf
T = tfidf.T
side_length = len(A)

for i in range(side_length):
    for j in range(side_length):
        if j < i:
            # avoid calculate lower triangle and diagonal
            continue
        maxtrix[i,j] = A(i)* T(j)
```

from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37026/string-matching-and-clustering/37059#37059), I see numpy has `np.apply_along_axis(d, 0, _)` to only calculate upper triangle, but `scipy.sparse` don't.

**update:**

No matter how a large a dataset is, only calculate upper triangle would cost less cpu resource.I am not familiar with matrix calculation, curiosity make me to ask this question(how to only calculate upper triangle in sparse matrix), not for solving a memory error.

Comment: You're likely to run into issues with fill-in. `tfidf * tfidf.T` is probably going to be quite dense - for example, if you had just one dense column in `tfidf` (i.e. a single feature present in all documents) then your `sml_matrix` would be 100% dense, even if the rest of your features occur very sparsely. If you assumed that `tfidf * tfidf.T` was fully dense, could you even fit just its upper triangle in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can win a 2 memory factor with some tricks, but data size always grows...

So it seems better to live with that and split the Dataframe in chunks.
You can do something like that :

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(12)) # as a mini exemple
maxsize=4
df['group']=df.index//maxsize
df.set_index('group',append=True,inplace=True)
df2=df.reorder_levels([1,0])

from itertools import combinations

print(df)
for i,j in (combinations(df2.index.levels[0],2)):
    print (df2.loc[[i,j]])
    #or do something else.
```

Then df is :

```
                  0
    group          
0   0      0.388695
1   0      0.982780
2   0      0.632253
3   0      0.445638
4   1      0.346920
5   1      0.789327
6   1      0.311657
7   1      0.548581
8   2      0.688201
9   2      0.824547
10  2      0.980281
11  2      0.314968
```

And chunks are:

```
                  0
group           
0     0    0.388695
      1    0.982780
      2    0.632253
      3    0.445638
1     4    0.346920
      5    0.789327
      6    0.311657
      7    0.548581
                  0
group           
0     0    0.388695
      1    0.982780
      2    0.632253
      3    0.445638
2     8    0.688201
      9    0.824547
      10   0.980281
      11   0.314968
                  0
group           
1     4    0.346920
      5    0.789327
      6    0.311657
      7    0.548581
2     8    0.688201
      9    0.824547
      10   0.980281
      11   0.314968
```

Then compute and collect the good things on each chunk.
you will make twice some computations, but no more memory error.

Comment: Thank your answers. I know shrink dataset can avoid memory error, but the purpose of this question is to solve "how to only calculate upper triangle".

Comment: with Numpy, i don't think it's possible in a efficient way. You can do it with Numba or Cython, but since dot is one of the more optimized function of numpy, you will have a lot of work to  achieve the same speed.